# force https aws elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have my symfony application deployed in AWS elastic beanstalk instance.

I want only use the HTTPS protocol. I have created this file: 
.elasticbeanstalk/https_rewrite.cfg.yml with this content:

```
files:
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf:
content: "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so\n\
    RewriteEngine On\n\
    # This will enable the Rewrite capabilities\n\
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on\n\
    # This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS\n\
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]    \n"
group: root
mode: "000644"
owner: root
```

But it doesn't work.

I use the certificate generate by Amazon.

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: yes I read this link but what am I doing with ?                                                                         files:
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf:
    content: "RewriteEngine On\n
              RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http\n
              RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]"
    group: root
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root      This content not work.

Comment: Yes I use a load balancer and yes I think the request is not redirect to https because we have the security logo in my browser. Is it possible to use load balancer with force http to https for have the security logo in my browser ?

Comment: Yes but why i don't see the green padlock in my browser (Firefox)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to move the file to .ebextension directory.

Thank you.